# Tuleap-Parent and child project access

Tags: tuleap

I have mapped a project in tuleap as parent and another as a child for same. The members of parent project do not have permission access to the child project. (or) could somebody help me to link two project in tuleap.
thanks in advance. My tuleap version is 7.0.99.45

Answer (score 0):

The parent-child relationship of projects in Tuleap does not work this way. In fact, it is meant to work with Gerrit's integration. The idea behind this is to be able to use the rights management system of Gerrit that includes support for Parent-child relationship from Tuleap.